# SVG viewbox not always scaled to width and height

Tags: svg, scaling

I'm using several libraries to generate SVG images in-browser, which can be bounced off the server through [svgexport](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport) to generate PNGs or JPEGs at user-specified resolutions.  (This works as expected.)

I'd like to offer the user the option of downloading the SVG that gets fed into the conversion, with the resolution used to set the width and height attributes.  When I do that, the viewbox is not scaled to the specified width and height, but is padded so that the image occupies the original size area in the upper left.

While looking for solutions, I found images in the W3C documentation that illustrate the problem.  If you open these images in Chrome and use the inspector to change the width and height properties,

- [ViewBox.svg](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/coords/ViewBox.svg) will expand to fill the width and height (linked from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute))
- [PreserveAspectRatio.svg](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/coords/PreserveAspectRatio.svg) will be padded to stay in the upper left (linked from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute))

This does not appear related the presence or value of the`preserveAspectRatio` property, or the nesting of `svg` tags.  My files are rendered as padded rather than scaled in Chrome/Chromium, Firefox, Safari/WebKit, Opera, Inkscape, and Gapplin.

**How do I ensure that my SVG is scaled rather than padded to fill the width and height?**

Comment: Add a [mcve] to the question. Be sure to indicate also how you would like it to render.

Comment: Also: [Be careful with your viewBox](https://dbushell.com/2016/03/01/be-careful-with-your-viewbox/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The viewbox is not scaled when it's entered as `viewbox` rather than `viewBox`; svg attribute names are case sensitive.

The second link does not have a viewBox attribute, and adding a viewbox (lowercase) attribute has no effect.

Comment: Just spent quite a while figuring this out... Crazily in the VS Code Preview the SVG was scaled properly, so it seems the render engine there is case insensitive.

Comment: @frankenapps that sounds like a bug worth reporting to the vs code team - possibly along with the suggestion that their syntax highlighting point out miscased tags.